# Does FileStream in C# have a maximum File size it can use?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, filestream

So in visual studio I have a simple fileStream that looks like this:

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Filename,FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write))           
{                    
    long fourgigs = 1073741824L * 4;

    for (int y = 0; y < fourgigs; y++)
    {
       byte[] b = { 1 };

       stream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
    }
}
```

I have limited it to writing four gigabytes to a file, because once the file exceeds four gigabytes i get an error saying "Not enough space on disk". So i'm just wondering is this a limit on FileStream or perhaps because i'm writing to a text file?

For clarification the disk is not out of space, the disk has several hundred gigs. Any help on this matter is apperciated, thx.

edit:So I did some experimenting, originally I was  trying to write to a USB drive, i instead decided to write to my normal hard drive. Interestingly enough my normal hard drive will write well beyond four gigs, while the USB will not. I'm still unsure why this is. Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: did you have a 4GB or Bigger file on your FileSystem ?

Comment: That is an infinite loop, as your loop variable is `int` and will overflow to -2,147,483,648 after int.MaxValue of 2,147,483,647.

Comment: thanks David browne i got an error when i just ran and was wondering why it went over four gigs

Comment: @NPE there is no such thing as an `unsigned long long int` in C#

Comment: @CetinBasoz: Not true. It depends on the file system what file size you can have max

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft remark seems pertinent try with UInt64 instead of int or long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You noticed that this works for your local disk but not for the USB drive.

Most likely, the reason is that your USB drive is formatted as FAT32 or something similar. This filesystem can't handle files bigger than 4GB

Comment: Thanks that's what was happening, i didn't know that was a thing.

Comment: You are saying the same thing I did but probably it was about wording :)